# Meaning of 無数の人工物が細やかな直線を交差させている in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> 遠く見下ろす街。無数の人工物が細やかな直線を交差させている。背の羽根をかかとの方向へ引き絞るように翻すと、俺の身体は推進力を得て一気に中空を滑り出した。猛スピードで逃げてゆく景色を片目に俺は、「天使か」と呟いていた。

I came across this sentence and I've some doubts with the part "無数の人工物が細やかな直線を交差させている".
My personal translation would be something like "A modest straight line is crossing with innumerable artificial objects (with I think is referring to 街)". Probably my interpretation is wrong so I do like to know what is the meaning of this part in specific.

Comment: Any more contexts? Probably they are rays from artificial objects such  as buildings, stations, cars or whatever people use in a city. In my image, shining lights that radiate and cross each other forms layers like spokes of bicycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Innumerable artificial objects forms a mesh of fine intersecting lines"

You might want to check [definition 1.ア](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B4%B0%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B#:%7E:text=%E3%81%93%E3%81%BE%E2%80%90%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B%E3%80%90%E7%B4%B0%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%8F%E2%96%BD%E6%BF%83%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B%E3%80%91&text=%EF%BC%91%20%E4%B8%80%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3,%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%86%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%AE%E6%BF%83%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%80%82&text=%E3%8B%91%E8%89%B2%E3%81%AE%E6%BF%83%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%80%82) of [細]{こま}やか.